# Bootstrap cutting part of ShareThis buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to embed [ShareThis](http://www.sharethis.com/get-sharing-tools/#) code in to a website created using Bootstrap.

Problem is that for some reason the bottom of both buttons is cut off and also I cannot seem to center the buttons using Bootstrap column offsets as it seems impossible to get both buttons exactly centered using this method.

What is the solution here?

[image]

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <span class='st_facebook_vcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
      <span class='st_twitter_vcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with the ShareThis buttons, do you have a link to view the site?

Regarding the centering, currently you are using a `col-lg-12` which means it takes up 100% of the width and everything inside (your buttons) would be left aligned by default. You wouldn't necessarily need to use the bootstrap column offset but just put the spans in a wrapper as below. You can find out more about the Bootstrap Grid here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="social-wrapper">
      <span class='st_facebook_vcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
      <span class='st_twitter_vcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add `text-align`:`center` to the wrapper.

```
.social-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check out a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hez7pqbo/